# CCRT = Constant case CRT: $ $ if $\,p,q\,$ are coprime then$\,x\equiv a\pmod{\! p},\ x\equiv a\pmod{\! q}\iff x\equiv a\pmod{\!pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Problem:** Find the units digit of $3^{100}$ using Fermat's Little Theorem (FLT).

**My Attempt:** By FLT we have $$3^1\equiv 1\pmod2\Rightarrow 3^4\equiv1\pmod 2$$ and $$3^4\equiv 1\pmod 5.$$ Since $\gcd(2,5)=1$ we can multiply the moduli and thus, $3^4\equiv 1\pmod {10}\Rightarrow3^{4*25}\equiv 1\pmod{10}.$ So the units digit is $1.$

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "since gcd =1 we can multiply the moduli."  Rather, since $3^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ and $3^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, by CRT, $3^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}.$

Comment: @B.Goddard.It is valid that if $\gcd (x,y)=1$ with $xy\ne 0 ,$ and $a\equiv b \pmod x$ and $a\equiv b \pmod y,$ then $a\equiv b\pmod {xy}.$ Because if $x$ and $y$ both divide $a-b,$ with $\gcd (x,y)=1$, then $xy$ divides $a-b.$  But I've not seen it phrased that way either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours is a valid, clean argument. It is based on this:

> If $m$ and $n$ divide $a$, then $\text{lcm}(m,n)$ divides $a$.

In your case, you have that $2$ and $5$ divide $3^4-1$, and so $10=\text{lcm}(2,5)$ divides $3^4-1$.

Comment: My argument is based on the following fact: If $a\equiv b \pmod {n_1}$ and $a\equiv b \pmod {n_2}$ with $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=1$ then $a\equiv b \pmod {n_1n_2}$

Comment: @ShreyAryan, this follows from what I've written. Good job.

Comment: So I were to write this in an exam, then how should I go about it?

Comment: @ShreyAryan As what B. Goddard pointed out, your phrasing that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, hence I can multiply the congruences is odd (can be judged incorrect as well, even though the ultimate conclusion you are drawing is correct). You should go with what lhf has suggested.

Comment: @Shrey Yoru argument is indeed a special *constant* case of CRT - see my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Your proof is correct. It invokes a simple special case of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem when the values $\,a_1 = a_2\,$ are *constant*, say $\,a,\,$ which is equivalent to the following basic result

[UL = Universal property of LCM:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242)  $\ \rm \,\ j,k\mid n\!\!\color{#0a0}{\overset{\rm UL\!\!}\iff} {\rm lcm}(j,k)\mid n$

**CCRT = Constant case CRT** $\ $ If $\rm \,a,p,q\,$ are integers and $\rm \,\gcd(p,q) = 1\,$ then

$$\begin{align}\rm  x\equiv a\!\!\pmod{p}\\ \rm x\equiv a\!\!\pmod{q}\end{align}\iff\,\rm  x\equiv a\!\!\pmod{pq}\qquad$$

**Proof** $\ $ Below I sketch the key ideas in four proofs.

$\rm(1)\ \ \ x \equiv a\pmod {pq}\:$ is clearly a solution, and the solution is $\color{#C00}{\textit{unique}}$ $\!\!\pmod{\rm\!pq}\,$ [by CRT.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242)

$\rm(2)\ \ \ p,q\:|\:x\!-\!a\!\!\color{#0a0}{\overset{\rm UL\!\!}\iff} lcm(p,q)\:|\:x\!-\!a.\:$ [Further](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318880/242) $\rm\:\gcd(p,q)=1\!\iff\!lcm(p,q) = pq.$

$(3)\ \, $ By [Euclid's Lemma:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) $\rm\:(p,q)=1,\,\ p\mid nq\! =\!x\!-\!a\:\Rightarrow\:p\:|\:n\:\Rightarrow\:pq\:|\:nq = x\!-\!a.$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) for more proofs, elaboration, and generalizations.

**Remark** $\ $ This *constant-case optimization* of CRT arises frequently in practice so is well-worth memorizing, e.g. see [some prior posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+constant+case+crt) for many examples.

[Quite frequently,](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amath.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+powerful++tools+equalities)  $\color{#C00}{\textit{uniqueness}}\ \textit{theorems}\,$ provide powerful tools for **proving equalities.**

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this! +1

Comment: +1 I am shocked that someone downvoted this. The only reasonable explanation I can come up with is that another guy who answered this same question downvoted this. If that is true then the lack of sportsmanship is appalling.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase ‘Since gcd(2,5)=1 we can multiply the moduli’ is not clear at all. I would rather say something like  ‘since $3^4\equiv 1\mod 2$ and $\bmod5$, we have $3^4\equiv 1\mod \operatorname{lcm}(2,5)=10$’ by the Chinese remainder theorem.

That said, why make things more complicated than they are?

$3^2\equiv -1\mod 10$, hence $3^4\equiv (-1)^2=1\mod 10$, and finally $3^{10}=(3^4)^{25}\equiv 1\mod10$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I knew this solution but wanted to know whether the reasoning of my argument is sound or not. If possible please, try to address that issue in your answer.

Comment: @Shrey Aryan: your reasoning seems to be correct if I interpret your not very clear phrasing about $\gcd(2,5)$.

Comment: Thank you for replying (again)! I read the following in David Burton, Chapter 4: If $a\equiv b \pmod {n_1}$ and $a\equiv b \pmod {n_2}$ with $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=1$ then $a\equiv b \pmod {n_1n_2}$, but was very unsure about whether I've been applying it correctly or not.

Comment: It's OK, only the phrasing is not clear. The abstract version is ‘ the canonical map $\mathbf Z/n_1n_2\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z/n_1\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/n_2\mathbf Z$ is an isomorphism.’