# Prove by induction that, for all positive integers $n$ , if $\gcd(a,M_n)=1$ , then $a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_n−1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_n}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Suppose $M_n=p_1×p_2×⋯×p_n$  where $p_1,…,p_n$ are distinct primes. Prove by induction that, for all positive integers $n$ , if $\gcd(a,M_n)=1$  , then  $a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_n−1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_n}$..

I don't know how to connect the question with "induction". In other words, I've stuck by IC AND IH

Comment: Start with the case $n=1$ when $M_1=p_1$ or $M_1$ is a prime number itself. This is Fermat's little theorem. Then assume the expression is true for when $M_n$ is a product of $n$ distinct primes and use this to prove the expression for $M_{n+1}$-product of $n+1$ distinct primes.

Comment: i still don't understand how to do. can you tell me the ic and ih?

Comment: ic - initial condition? If so, then it's $M_1=p$, $p$-any prime, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. This needs to be proved by the way! Can you find ih (initial hypothesis) using my comment above as a hint?

Comment: @rtybase: Do it if you can. It is not easy and it would be a trick maybe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I should mention that this is a particular case of the [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $\gcd(a,M_n)=1 \Rightarrow a^{\varphi(M_n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_n}$ and [$\varphi(M_n) = (p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_n−1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

But, we are asked to use induction, so no shortcuts.

**Case 1 (IC).** $n=1$ which means $M_1=p_1$ or $M_1$ is a prime and $\gcd(a,M_1)=1$. This is [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) or $a^{p_1-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p_1}$ which is the same as $a^{p_1-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_1}$. This case is covered.

**Case 2 (IH)**. Let's assume the statement is true for a fixed $k$, i.e. for any $M_k$ such that $\gcd(a,M_k)=1$ and $M_k=p_1p_2⋯p_k$ product of $k$ distinct prime numbers $\Rightarrow a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_k}$.

Now we should prove the statement is also true for $M_{k+1}$ such that $\gcd(a,M_{k+1})=1$ and $M_{k}=p_1p_2⋯p_{k+1}$ product of $k+1$ distinct prime numbers.

Let's split $M_{k+1}=M_{k}\cdot p_{k+1}$. Because $\gcd(a,M_{k+1})=1 \Rightarrow \gcd(a,M_{k})=1$ too and from the hypothesis $$a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_k}$$
and
$$a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)} \equiv 1^{p_{k+1}-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_k}$$
Because $\gcd(a,M_{k+1})=1$, then $\gcd(a,p_{k+1})=1$ and $\gcd(a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)} ,p_{k+1})=1$. And using Fermat's little threorem 
$$\left(a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)}\right)^{p_{k+1}-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p_{k+1}}$$
Altogether:
$$a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)} \equiv 1\pmod{M_k}$$
$$a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p_{k+1}}$$
Given $\gcd(M_k,p_{k+1})=1$ and

- $M_k|\left(a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)}−1 \right)$ and
- $p_{k+1}|\left(a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)}−1 \right)$

or $M_k\cdot Q_1=p_{k+1}\cdot Q_2=a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)}−1$, for some integers $Q_1, Q2$, leading to $p_{k+1}|Q_1$, we have:
$$a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_kp_{k+1}}$$
which is
$$a^{(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)(p_{k+1}-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_{k+1}}$$
And we proved the statement for $k+1$ assuming it's true for $k$.

Comment: You need to *justify* the inference after "Altogether". Presumably you use CRT (simple constant case or equivalents - see [thsi answer)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque it is based on the fact that $\gcd(M_k, p_{k+1}) =1$ and $M_k | a^{...} -1$ and $p_{k+1} | a^{...} -1$ or $M_k\cdot Q_1 = p_{k+1}\cdot Q_2 = a^{...} -1$ leading to $p_{k+1} | Q_1$.

Comment: That's the 2nd method in my linked answer. In any case, you should state that justification *explicitly* in the answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque I just updated my answer.