# Prove that $(p - 1)! \equiv (p - 1) \pmod{p(p - 1)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that: $$(p - 1)! \equiv p - 1 \pmod{p(p - 1)}$$

In text it's not mentioned that $p$ is prime, but I checked and this doesn't hold for non-prime, so I guess $p$ is prime ..
I know that $(p - 1)! \equiv -1 \equiv p - 1 \pmod p$,
and $(p - 1)! \equiv 0 \equiv (p - 1) \pmod{p - 1}$,
the problem is that I don't know how to combine these.
Is it true that then we have: $(p - 1)! \equiv (p - 1)^2 = p^2 - p - p + 1 \equiv - p + 1 = - (p - 1) \pmod{p(p - 1)}$, which is not the desired result .. ?
Or I need to multiply both sides of congruences ?
What are the laws for congruences that allow me to do this ? (I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to ask).

Comment: What you need is the so called Chinese Remainder Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: It's special case $\,a=0,\,b=-1$ (Wilson) of the simple CRT problem below, e.g. see [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) 
  
$$\begin{align}&
x\equiv a\!\!\pmod{p\!-\!1}\\ 
&x\equiv b\!\!\pmod{p}\end{align}
\iff x\equiv a + (p\!-\!1)(a\!-\!b) \!\!\pmod {p(p\!-\!1)}\qquad$$

Comment: But if we only need to *verify* (vs. *discover*) the result then it is trivial: note that for $\,x:= (p-1)!\,$ we have that the congruence $\,x\equiv p\!-\!1\,$ holds both mod $\,p\,$ (by Wilson) and mod $\,p\!-\!1,\,$ hence it also holds mod their lcm=product $p(p\!-\!1)$ by [CCRT = Constant-case CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) in the 2nd linked dupe.

Comment: **Or** apply below  $\ an\bmod ap =\ a(n\bmod p) =$ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to factor out $\,a=p\!-\!1\,$

$$(p\!-\!1)!\bmod (p\!-\!1)p \,=\, (p\!-\!1)\underbrace{\left[{\dfrac{(p\!-\!1)!}{p\!-\!1}\bmod p}\right]}_{\textstyle\equiv (-1)/(-1)\equiv 1} =\:\! p\!-\!1\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to the coprime moduli $p$ and $p-1$.

However, if you can't use CRT, you can simply observe $(p-1)!-(p-1)$ is divisible by $p-1$ (obvious factor) and by $p$ (Wilson's), so it is divisible by their least common multiple $\operatorname{lcm}(p,p-1)=p(p-1)$.

Comment: Oooh right, so in general, if $x \equiv y (mod a)$ and $x \equiv y (mod b)$ then $x \equiv y (mod [a, b])$, right ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You final paragraph is a special case of CCRT - see my 2nd comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Theorem. If $a|c$, $b|c$ and $(a,b)=1$ then $ab|c$

We know that $ (p,p-1)=1$ and also $p-1|(p-1)!-(p-1)$

By wilson theorem $p|(p-1)!+1$. Then $p|[(p-1)!+1]-p$

Therefore $p(p-1)| (p-1)!-(p-1)$