# How can I solve a system of 2 congruences?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, congruence-relations

I have this system of congruences $ p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $ p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and the solution written in the book is $ p \equiv 11 \pmod {12 }$ but I do not know how? Could anyone explain this for me please?

I feel like I can not apply Chinese remainder theorem as it requires at least 3 congruences ..... am I correct?

Comment: What don't you understand?  One of your tags refers to the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)...are you familiar with that theorem?

Comment: No, it doesn't require three congruences.  Just proceed as usual.

Comment: **Hint** $\ 3,4\mid p+1\iff 3\cdot 4\mid p+1\,$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply the Chinese remainder theorem.  For this particular system, the solution is simple:

$p\equiv-1\pmod4$ and $p\equiv-1\pmod3$ means $4|p+1$ and $3|p+1$, so $12|p+1$;

i.e., $p\equiv-1\pmod{12}$.

[Note:  $-1\equiv11\pmod{12}$.]

Comment: Very nice I did not think it will be very easy like this by CRT ..... Thanks a lot

Comment: Solving $p\equiv a \pmod n$ and $p\equiv a \pmod m$ is particularly easy; $p\equiv a \pmod n$ and $p\equiv b \pmod m$ requires a bit more effort

Comment: Right.  This is the constant case of CRT.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Bezout coefficients, like such:  $-1\cdot3+1\cdot4=1$.

Then we write $x=3\cdot(-3)+2\cdot 4=-1\cong {11}\pmod{12}$.

Comment: I can see in the first step that you are writing the gcd of 4 and 3 as a linear combination of 4 and 3 .... what about the second step of finding x?

Comment: Take that same equation and multiply the terms by the residues in the "opposite order".  That is, I put the residue mod $4$ with the term with the $3$;  and the residue mod $3$ with the term with the $4$.  Do you follow?

Comment: See Bernard's answer for a good visual.

Answer (score 2):

For a problem like this, simple trial and error suffices.

For a general method:  Start with $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.  That tells us that $p=3+4k$.  Now we move to the second congruence, contingent on the first.   $$p\equiv 2\pmod 3\iff 3+4k\equiv 2\pmod 3\iff k\equiv 2 \pmod 3$$ $$\iff k=2+3l\iff p = 11+12l\iff p\equiv 11 \pmod {12}$$

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

One starts from Bézout's identity:
$\;4u+3v=1\quad(u,v\in\mathbf Z)$, say $4-3=1$. By the *Chinese remainder theorem*,
$$\begin{cases}
p\equiv \color{red}{\alpha\mod 4}\\
p\equiv\color{blue}{\beta\mod 3}
\end{cases}\iff p\equiv \color{blue}{\beta}\,\color{red}{4}u+\color{red}{\alpha}\,\color{blue}{3}v\mod 3\cdot4 $$

Comment: I had a mind to do this (with the colors).  But didn't follow through.

Comment: Great minds think together ;o). Joking aside, I think it's a good way to insist on which value goes with which modulus in the solution formula.

Comment: It's perfect for it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$p=3+4m,p=2+3n$$ so $$1=3n-4m$$ solving this Diophantine equation we get
$$m=2+3C,n=4+4C$$ so $$p=11+12C$$