# Idempotent elements in a modulo n ring

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, idempotents

I'm trying to find the idempotent elements of the ring ($\Bbb Z_{36} $, +, $ \cdot $) so I "split" it into $ \operatorname{Idemp}(\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_9) $, meaning $\operatorname{Idemp}(\Bbb Z_4) \times \operatorname{Idemp}(\Bbb Z_9) $.

I know the idempotent elements of $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_9$, but I don't understand how to "transform" them back to $\Bbb Z_{36}$. For example, I know that pair $(\widetilde{0}, \bar{1})$ in $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_9$ corresponds to $\widehat{28}$ in $\Bbb Z_{36}$, and that $(\widetilde{1}, \bar{0})$ corresponds to $\widehat{9}$, but why?

If there are other ways to find the idempotents for a large $n$, it's OK, but I wish to understand this particular case I just asked. Thanks!

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: To see how to see how to solve simultaneous congruences, you can take a look at my answer to this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260111/how-can-i-solve-a-system-of-2-congruences/3260173#3260173)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to transform $28$ from $\Bbb Z_{36}$ to $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_9$: Then we just reduce the normal way for modular arithmetic:

- In $\Bbb Z_4$, $28$ reduces to $0$
- In $\Bbb Z_9$, $28$ reduces to $1$

Translating the other way (from $(0,1)$ to $28$) is a bit more tricky, and for small examples, I usually brute force it. In this case:

> I know that whatever the answer is, it reduces to $1$ in $\Bbb Z_9$, so my options are $1, 10, 19$ and $28$. Of these, only $28$ reduces to $0$ in $\Bbb Z_4$, so that's the answer.

This is the second approach suggested by the [Wikipedia article on the Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation). The third approach uses the actual proof of the theorem to find the correct remainder, and it's more constructive, albeit somewhat longer for this small example:

> First, find $a, b$ such that $4a + 9b = 1$. This may be done by the extended Euclidean algorithm, or in a simple case like this, just immediately spotting that $9-8 = 1$: We get $a = -2, b = 1$. We now get a solution as
>   $$
> \color{blue}0\cdot \color{red}{1\cdot 9} + \color{blue}1\cdot\color{red}{(-2)\cdot 4} = -8\equiv_{36}28
> $$
>   where the blue numbers are the components of our element in $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_9$, and the red parts are the terms from $-2\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 9 = 1$. Note that the component from $\Bbb Z_4$ is multiplied by the $9$ term from $-2\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 9$, and vice versa.

The idea of this third approach is that from $4\cdot (-2) + 9\cdot 1 = 1$, we get that $4\cdot (-2)\in \Bbb Z_{36}$ corresponds to $(0,1)\in \Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_9$ and $9\cdot 1\in \Bbb Z_{36}$ corresponds to $(1,0)$. So we just add however many we need of each, and we get our answer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: For integers $m,n\geq 2$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$, the mapping 
$${\Bbb Z}_{mn}\rightarrow{\Bbb Z}_m\times {\Bbb Z}_n:x\mapsto (x\mod m,x\mod n)$$ is a ring isomorphism.

The surjectivity is usually proved by the Chinese remainder theorem, i.e., the simultaneaous congruences
$$x\equiv a\mod m\quad\mbox{and}\quad x\equiv b\mod n$$
have a unique solution $x$ (an integer $x$ with $0\leq x <mn$).

SOLUTION: The solution is $x=b-yn(b-a)$ where $1=yn+zm$.