# Calculating Nil(Z_n) faster

Tags: modular-arithmetic, nilpotence

As far as I know, in order to calculate Nil(Z_n) I need to calculate each number raised to different values and see if I get 0. That is a very slow and inefficient way, in my opinion.

Is there any other faster way to do this?

For example, U(Z_n) is equal with the numbers with the property (number, n) = 1.

Is there any similar thing for Nil(Z_n)?

Thanks.

Comment: $x^k\equiv0\pmod n$ for some $k \iff $   all the prime factors of $n$ divide $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integer $n$,

the nilpotent elements of the finite ring   $ \mathbb {Z} /n\mathbb {Z}$ are all of the multiples of the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) of $n$,

which is  the product of the distinct prime numbers dividing $ n$.

For example, rad$(12)=$rad$(2^2\cdot3)=2\cdot3=6$,

so the nilpotent elements of $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ are multiples of $6$.

Comment: Can you help me with an example? Let's say, for n = 12.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking I should do an example.  rad$(12)=$rad$(2^2\cdot3)=2\cdot3=6$, so the nilpotent elements of $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ are multiples of $6$

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. Do you mind telling me if there is any rule for Idem(Z_n)? :)

Comment: Also, if we can't calculate the radical (for example n=10 so rad(2*5) ) does that mean that Nil(Z_n) contains only 0?

Comment: Yes, and for idempotents, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265028/idempotent-elements-in-a-modulo-n-ring); basically, idempotents are $0$ and $1$ for odd prime powers, and use the Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Thanks a lot :)