# Solving system Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have to calculate $2019x \equiv18^{2019} \, mod \, 45$

This is equivalent to: \begin{cases} 2019x  \equiv 18^{2019} \, \text{mod} \,  5   \\ 2019x \equiv 18^{2019} \, \text{mod} \, 9  \end{cases}
We know that $2019x \,  mod \, 5 = 4x $ and $2019x \,  mod \, 9 = 3x $. So we get:
\begin{cases} 4x  \equiv 1 \, \text{mod} \,  5   \\ 3x \equiv 0 \, \text{mod} \, 9  \end{cases}. We can now multiply by the inverses. So we get: 
\begin{cases} x  \equiv 4 \, \text{mod} \,  5   \\ x \equiv 0 \, \text{mod} \, 3  \end{cases}. The last step will be here to use the Chinese Remainder theorem. I'm asking if my method is correct because it is the first time I'm practicing this kind of questions and I want to be sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the congruence mod $5$ starts with a wrong right hand side, and the congruence mod $9$ is a little tricky because $9$ is not a prime (but it is a power of a prime).  Check over your work.

Comment: Thought $3x \equiv 0 mod 9$ iff $3x = 9q$ with q an integer so $x = 3q$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  It will just be a little tricky piecing things back to get the solutions mod $45$.  So one way to think about combining the congruences mod $5$ and $9$ is to list all three of the mod $9$ possibilities.

Comment: Looks good to me... using CRT you will get one unique solution in mod $15$. Then you can add multiples of $15$ to that to get unique solutions in mod $45$.

Comment: How did you get $18^{2019}\equiv 1 \pmod 5$?  For that matter how did you get $18^{2019}\equiv 0 \pmod 9$.

Comment: Oh... and $3$ does not have an inverse $\mod 9$.... and how did you drop it from $9$ to $3$.

Comment: @ganeshie8  Isn't "unique solution***s***" an oxymoron?

Comment: @fleablood OP did do it correctly by cancelling $3$ - see the comment above.

Comment: I didn't say the OP didn't do it correctly.  I asked the OP to tell us what he was doing and why.

Comment: Lol @fleablood  XD that occurred to me while typing haha Then the phrase "3 unique solutions" must be a punishable crime :P

Comment: What is the abbrevation for OP?

Comment: @Kabouter9 OP = Original Post(er), i.e. the initial post (or its author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is correct but it should be $\!\bmod 5\!:\ {-}x\equiv 4x\equiv \color{#c00}2,\,$ so $\,x\equiv -2\equiv 3,\,$ and also $\,x\equiv 0\equiv 3\pmod{\!3} \iff x\equiv 3\pmod{\!15}\,$ by LCM or [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) = Constant case CRT.

Answer (score 1):

$18^{2019} \equiv (-2)(-2)^{2018} \equiv (-2)(-1)^{1009} \equiv 2 \text{ (mod 5)}$

$2019 x \equiv -x \equiv 2 \Rightarrow x \equiv 3 \text{ (mod 5)}$

Luckily, the second congruence is $x \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 3)}$. No need for CRT, since 3|3

Combine both congruences: $$x \equiv 3 \text{ (mod 15)}$$