# Chinese Remainder Theorem to find possible element

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

the question is find all possible integers a which satisfy the following system of congruences

$a = 3 \mod 6$

$a = 4 \mod 7$

$a = 6 \mod 15$

but I find $a = 3 \mod 6$ is $105n= 3n  \mod 6$
and their $\gcd$ is $3$ not $1$ so in this question is it no solutuion?

Comment: A solution is $a=81$. So, there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to transform this system of congruences into the equivalent system with pairwise coprime moduli:
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 1 \mod 2, \\ x\equiv 0\mod 3, \\ x\equiv 4 \mod 7,\\ x\equiv 1\mod 5.
\end{cases}
Let's find the solutions of the last two congruences. Starting from a Bézout's relation between the moduli: $\;3\cdot 5-2\cdot 7=1$, we deduce instantly that
$$x\equiv 4\cdot3\cdot 5-1\cdot2\cdot 7=46\equiv 11\mod 35.$$
We could proceed in the same way for the other two moduli, but it is faster to observe first that, among these solutions, $x$ has to be *odd* by the first congruence, so $\;x\equiv 11\bmod 70$, and ultimately as the second congruence is $x\equiv 0\bmod3$,  Bézout's relation $\;70-23\cdot 3=1$ yields
$$x\equiv 11\cdot(-23\cdot 3)=-759\equiv \color{red}{81\bmod 210}.$$

Comment: Actually it is *not* simpler to make that transformation since it obfscates the innate structure which can by exploited by CCRT - see my answer.

Comment: Quite ingenious to use the constant case! (+1)

Comment: why not use $6=-3\cdot -2$ ?

Comment: Usually, the moduli are taken among  positive integers.

Comment: I'm not a purist.

Comment: We can use CCRT in the above answer also: $\, x\equiv 1\pmod{\!10},\ x\equiv -3\pmod{\!21}\ $ hence $\bmod 10\!:\ \,1\equiv x\equiv -3\!+\!21j\equiv -3\!+\!j\iff j\equiv 4.\,$ Therefore $\, x = -3\!+\!21(4\!+\!10n) = 81\!+\!210n.\,$ @Roddy Why?

Comment: just thougjt getting rid of all the negative 3's would help.

Answer (score 1):

By [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242): $\ a\equiv -3\pmod{\!6\ \&\ 7}\iff a\equiv \color{#c00}{-3\pmod{\!42}}$

$\!\bmod 15\!:\,\ 6 \equiv a\equiv \color{#c00}{-3\!+\!42j}\equiv -3-3j\iff 3j\equiv -9\, \smash[t]{\overset{\large \div 3}\iff}\color{#0a0}{\bmod 5\!:\,\ j\equiv} -3\equiv\color{#0a0}2$

Hence we infer $\ a = -3\!+\!42(\color{#0a0}{2\!+\!5n}) =\, \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{81+ 210n}$