# Find smallest $x, y$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find smallest natural numbers $x,y$ such that

$$ 49x = 125y.$$

Will this require some special modular arithmetic property or am I missing something?

Comment: x=125n and y=49n for any integer n.

Comment: @DietrichBurde 0 is not being considered a natural number here

Comment: If you must use modular arithmetic than $\, n\equiv 0\pmod{\!49\ \&\ 125}\iff n\equiv 0\pmod{\!45\cdot 125}\ $ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242)

Answer (score 0):

Not at all: it only requires high school arithmetic. This common number is nothing else than the l.c.m. of $49$ and $125$. Now these numbers are coprime, so …

Comment: will it just be $$ x = 125 $$ and $$y = 49$$

Comment: Yes, absolutely!