# Solving Linear congruence using backward substitution

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Use the method of back substitution to find all integers $x$ such that $x ≡ 1 \mod 5$,
$x ≡ 2 \mod 6 $, and $x ≡ 3 \mod 7$.
Solution: The first congruence can be rewritten as an equality,
$x = 5t + 1$, where $t$ is an integer. Substituting this expression for $x$ into the second congruence
tells us that
$5t + 1 ≡ 2 \mod 6$,
which can be solved to show that $t ≡ 5 $ (mod $6$) (as the reader should verify).

Can someone verify that and show me how to do it?

Comment: If $5t+1\equiv2$, then (subtract $1$ from both sides) $5t\equiv1$, so (multiply both sides by $5$ or $-1$, which is its own inverse) $t\equiv5\pmod6$

Comment: Thank you, Tanner. I am supposed to do this without the knowledge of inverse since the textbook is arriving at that. So I took a long way, found a multiple of 5, greater than multiple of 6 by 1, which is 25 = 5*5 and that gave me t = 5. and later I realised that is basically finding inverse but like brute force.

Comment: Easier to use [CCRT = Constant case CRT:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) $\ x\equiv -4\pmod{\!5,6,7}\iff x\equiv -4\pmod{\!5\cdot 6\cdot 7}\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve $$5t+1\equiv2\pmod6,$$

subtract $1$ from both sides:  $$5t\equiv1\pmod6.$$

To get  $t\equiv5\pmod6$ from that, multiply both sides by $5$.

In general, if $a\equiv b\pmod n$, then $a+c\equiv b+c\pmod n$ and $a\times c\equiv b\times c\pmod n$.