# What are the last two digits of $139^{139^{100}}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know that I have to utilize (mod 100) for the problem.

Getting use of Euler's theorem as $(139, 100) = 1$ yields

$$139^{{139}^{100}} \equiv 139^{{139}^{100} \pmod{\Phi(100)}} \pmod{100}$$

$$ \equiv 139^{{139}^{100} \pmod{40}} \pmod{100}.$$

How to proceed from this point?

Comment: Use the same idea to determine $139^{100}\equiv 19^{100} \mod 40$

Comment: And, since $\phi(40)=16$, $$19^{100}\equiv19^4\cdot(19^{16})^6\equiv19^4\cdot1\bmod{40}$$

Comment: $19^{100} = (20-1)^{100}$.  If you expand by binomial theorem, every term is divisible by $40$ except the last one, which equals $1$.

Comment: I'd personally consider it mod $8$ and $5$ and use Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Or use $19^2\equiv1$.

Comment: $\bmod 10\!:\ k:=139^{100}\equiv (-1)^{100}\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{k= 1+10j}\,$ so  $\!\begin{align}\bmod 100\!:\ 139^k\equiv (-1\!+\!40)^k\equiv&\, (-1)^k + (-1)^{k-1} 40\color{#c00} k\ \ {\rm by}\ \ 40^2\equiv 0\ \ \&\ \ \rm Binomial\ Thm\\
\equiv &\ {-}1 + 40(\color{#c00}{1+10j})\equiv -1+40
\end{align}$

Comment: $\begin{align} &\bmod 8\!:\ 139\equiv\ 3\,\ \ \ \&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3^2\,\equiv\ 1\\
& \bmod 5\!:\ 139\equiv -1\ \ \&\ \ (-1)^2\equiv 1\end{align}$ so $\,139^2\equiv 1\bmod 5,8\,$ so also $\!\bmod 40\,$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lemma : $N^{20k} \equiv 1 \bmod 100$ for any natural number N that is coprime to 100 and any natural number k.

This is because $\lambda(100) = 20$. (See [Carmichael Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function))
So we only have to find $139^{100} \bmod 20$

$$139 \equiv -1 \bmod 20 \implies 139^{100} \equiv -1^{100} \equiv 1 \bmod 20$$
Therefore $$139^{139^{100}} \equiv 139^{20k+1} \equiv 139 \equiv 39 \bmod 100$$

Comment: You have to justify your lemma.

Comment: Btw your lemma is not true.

Comment: I have corrected it @Jakobian

Answer (score 2):

You want to evaluate $139^{100}\bmod{40}$. Note that $139\equiv19\bmod{40}$.

Finally, since $19=20-1$, $19^2=20^2-2\cdot20+1$,

$19^2\equiv1\bmod{40}$.

Thus, $$139^{19^{100}}\equiv139^1\equiv39\bmod{100}$$